# CSS3 Transition + Transform not working in Safari, but working in Chrome

Tags: css, safari, transform

The following Fiddle demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ydLyzk8c/

In the new versions of Firefox, Chrome, & Opera, the effect I'm trying to create works: When the document loads, scale-transform each item in turn (from `4,4` to `1,1`) and increase the opacity from 0 to 1 simultaneously.

However, in both Safari 8 on Mac & iOS Safari 7 & 8, no scale transform is present - only an opacity fadein. I'm sure I've got all the necessary vendor prefixes:

```
    -webkit-transform:-webkit-scale(1,1);
    -moz-transform:-moz-scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform:-ms-scale(1,1);
    -o-transform:-o-scale(1,1);
transform:scale(1,1);
```

But still, nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vendor prefix has to be at property not at value, so:

```
-o-transform: scale(1,1);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I got confused with specifying the vendor prefix for the transforms inside the transitions.